# ROLL_OVER event on all flash content

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, jwplayer

I'm trying to send a hover event from flash to js (in some browsers, the `mousemove` / `mouseover` events won't trigger over flash content). I've tried to do     this:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function():void {
    ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Rolled over!!");
});
```

But it didn't work. I'm an AS newbie, can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: In some browsers... is a bit vague. Can you be a bit more specific so we can reproduce the error...

Comment: Well that doesn't really matter, but for the record it's on OSX Firefox. I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644203/capture-js-mousemouse-under-flash-movie-ff-mac is a similar issue

Comment: There is also event that catch when user move mouse out : stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeave); , You can always start listen from this . Anyway , it might be focus issue if You also click outside flash content.

Answer (score 0):

also, you have to define a function to the externalinterface to be called.. its a bit overhead:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionScript", receivedFromJavaScript);
```

more info here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html
use last example.